# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, heroku, deployment

```
--> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python

-----> Python app detected

-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.10

       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

-----> Installing python-3.9.10

-----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0

-----> Installing SQLite3

-----> Installing requirements with pip

       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from versions: none)

       ERROR: No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926018/10951070

Answer (score 0):

This is because `apturl` is not a pip package that can be installed. A question similar to yours was answered before [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191757/package-not-getting-installed-inside-docker-container-using-pip).

Furthermore, you can confirm that a package exists by searching it in [pypi](https://pypi.org/). If this is a package that's on a private repository, make sure to include the mirror in your pip configuration.