# While trying to install a python package I get an error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2

Tags: python, pycharm

I tried to install requirements.txt using Pycharm's install packages pop up, but also typed pip install apturl==0.5.2 when in virtual enviroment. Both don't work and give the same error. I updated django succesfully but I fail to update my requirements.txt as most packages can't be found. Google search and pycharm's troubleshooting didn't help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement for select requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910971/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-for-select-requirements)

Comment: It looks like there is [no such thing as apturl according to PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=apturl).